# Git push permission denied (publickey) but successfully authenticated

Tags: git, github, ssh

I want to push my commits to github with ssh. I get

> You've successfully authenticated

message after run `ssh -T git@github.com` command but when I want to push my commits I get this error:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I run `ssh-add -l` command and I get

`4096 SHA256:SREQ0/2G0mT+UxUmpLWmkMramBcFxnl+onFyXgwFENk ~/.ssh/work2_rsa (RSA) 4096 SHA256:gKPZ1Hxzc6eZ/NsgnoPaJsGbdWgQV54bYAXaTym3PfY ~/.ssh/work3_rsa (RSA)`

I run `git remote -v` and I get

```
origin  git@github.com:H-Ghadirian/UdacitySillySong.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:H-Ghadirian/UdacitySillySong.git (push)
sillySong   git@github.com:H-Ghadirian/UdacitySillySong.git (fetch)
sillySong   git@github.com:H-Ghadirian/UdacitySillySong.git (push)
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816966/github-permission-denied-publickey-but-i-got-youve-successfully-authenticat). Its very similar to my issue but `sudo` didn't solve my problem.

I also run `git push -u origin master` and get the same error :

> Permission denied (publickey).

I also read [Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly for git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547283/permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-for-gi) but my public key is in .ssh folder and thats not my case

I read this page: [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) and check all. Did I miss something?

What should I do?

**MacOS**: Sierra

**git version** 2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)

As [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) describe,I add `config` file to my `.ssh` folder and add

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work2_rsa
```

to it.

Comment: what happens when you run `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: Did you make sure that you have the correct access rights and that the repository exists?

Comment: @Buccleuch after `ssh-add -l` I get **4096 SHA256:SREQ0/2G0mT+UxUmpLWmkMramBcFxnl+onFyXgwFENk ~/.ssh/work2_rsa (RSA)
4096 SHA256:gKPZ1Hxzc6eZ/NsgnoPaJsGbdWgQV54bYAXaTym3PfY ~/.ssh/work3_rsa (RSA)**

Comment: @EdwardThomson what do you mean? I run commands with `sudo` and check repo multiple times.

Comment: you run git as root (`sudo`)? I think you're doing things wrong, this should not be necessary. In any case, check if git uses *that* SSH that you use when you do the `ssh -T`. Looks like git does not have the same SSH configuration. Check the `GIT_SSH` environment variable for example and related config settings.

Comment: Are you sure you added your public key to GitHub profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first what `git remote -v` does return:

- it needs to be a repo you own or you are a collaborator of
- it needs to be the right *ssh* url `git@github.com:<you>/<yourRepo.git>`
  (And not an https one [like in your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46363362/6309))

Just to be clear, you need to create the remote repo first on GitHub: pushing to a non-existing repo would generate that error.

Typically, an ssh url not working means said URL is not written the way ssh expects it.
And ssh might expect a different URL because of an ssh `config` file in `~/.ssh/config`.

> I run commands with `sudo` and check repo multiple times.

You did not run your `ssh git@github.com` with sudi, which means you also don't need `sudo` for your push commands.

Comment: I run this command and add it to my question. please tell me what should I do next

Comment: Try git push -u origin master

Comment: I run that and still get the same error. I add it to my question

Comment: @HamedGh Are p1 or p2 private repos? I don't see them in https://github.com/H-Ghadirian?tab=repositories

Comment: no,I just rename in question to make every thing simple :)) I rename again and update my question. UdacitySillySong is my repository

Comment: @HamedGh Do you have a file named 'config' in your ~/.ssh folder? (are you on Windows, Mac, Linux? what version of git are you using?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155193/discussion-between-hamed-gh-and-vonc).

Comment: For me, `ssh-add /somewhere/yourkey` helped in your exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your git config `core.sshCommand` is as intended.

I also ended up in this situation by copying my `.gitconfig` from `C:\Users\<User>\.gitconfig` to `~/.gitconfig` in WSL, without realizing however that that copied along the path to an ssh executable. In WSL that configuration shadowed the default; the default should run instead.

So I had to run

```sh
git config --global --unset core.sshCommand
```